# Rails multi word Model naming conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions, models

I have a lookup table called metadata_types in my database, which lists all the various types of metadata my app uses.

Metadata is the plural of Metadatum; should I have called the table metadatum_types?  In other words should the plurality be on both words in this case, or just the second?  Should the corresponding model then also be metadatum_type.rb (Class MetadatumType)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

metadatum_types is fine.
Rails only applies pluralization at the end of the model name.

The method is rather simple and can be found here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-pluralize ([code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6c367a0d787705746f262d0bd5ad8c4f13a8c809/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L23))

The inflections Rails applies to the name can be found here: [Inflector.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6c367a0d787705746f262d0bd5ad8c4f13a8c809/activesupport/lib)

Comment: Thanks - this seemed to better answer the question re: pluralization of first word vs. second.

Answer (score 9):

`metadata_types` for the table name is fine. From there, you can do

```
> "metadata_types".classify
=> "MetadataType"
```

so MetadataType would be the class name expected by rails.

This also works in reverse:

```
> "MetadataType".tableize
=> "metadata_types"
```